# Spring Boot SOAP WS: unable to generate .Net client

Tags: .net, spring-boot, soap

I have a Spring Boot 2.5.3 with a SOAP WS provider.
I use the `spring-boot-starter-web-services` and let SB generate the provider from my XSD and my @Endpoint annotated java class.

The service goes well and via soapUI I can test it.
When I try to build a .Net Framework 4.8 client giving the WSDL, the .Net generation tool fails somewhere il the WSDL.

I think this issue is related with SOAP protocol version.
My SB implementation use `DefaultWsdl11Definition` and that's the only available binding in WSDL.

The `dotnet svcutil` tool seems to assume 1.2 by default, instead.

Maybe I can try:

- Add SOAP 1.2 binding in spring boot ws
- Let the devtool understand SOAP 1.1

Any help on how to debug this?